# In Beamer, how can one have strikethrough text in the author setting (defined by a command) in the preamble?

Tags: beamer, macros, text-decorations

I have some beamer slides for which many commands are defined in the preamble before the document environment. The author setting is defined by an author variable which contains strikethrough text provided by the package `ulem`. The author setting is defined using this variable *in the preamble* for technical reasons.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% strikethrough
    \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\newcommand{\authorSpecification}{
    \sout{G.~Aad et.~al.}
}

\title{title}
%\author{test}
\author{\authorSpecification}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

When I try to compile this, I am presented with the following error:

```
! Argument of \UL@word has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.11 \author{\authorSpecification}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I've added a better solution, which works for the preamble too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `beamer` wants to pass the author information also as metadata for the PDF file and of course it's impossible to apply `\sout` there.

The usual solution is to exploit `\texorpdfstring`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\newcommand{\authorSpecification}{%
  \texorpdfstring{\sout{G.~Aad et.~al.}}{G. Aad et. al.}%
}

\title{title}
\author{\authorSpecification}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

And `pdfinfo` will show the following information:

```
Title:          title
Subject:        
Keywords:       
Author:         G. Aad et. al.
Creator:        LaTeX with Beamer class version 3.36
```

Having `\author` after `\begin{document}` would make the `Author` field empty.

One can avoid `\texorpdfstring` by providing a replacement for `\sout`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\makeatletter
% in PDF strings, we want \sout to be a no-op
% \@iden = \@firstofone just strips the braces off
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\sout\@iden}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\authorSpecification}{%
  \sout{G.~Aad et.~al.}%
}

\title{title}
\author{\authorSpecification}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

---

Using `\robustify{\sout}` (as proposed in another answer) would issue the warning

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\sout' on input line 13.
```

and the `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` command would be needed anyway to get rid of it.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently `\sout{...}` conflicts with beamer's `\author` command, perhaps it tries to make a typesetting in the preamble already.

Shifting the `\author` command into the document body works however:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% strikethrough
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\newcommand{\authorSpecification}{%
  \sout{G.~Aad et.~ al.}
}

\title{title}
%\author{test}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\author{\authorSpecification}
\frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

The problem is the fragile command `\sout`: Robustifying helps and `\author{\authorSpecification}` can be used in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% strikethrough
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\robustify\sout

\newcommand{\authorSpecification}{%
  \sout{G.~Aad et.~al.}
}

\title{title}
\author{\authorSpecification}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ChristienHupfer, I can use `\sout{...}` directly in title whitout any complain of LaTeX. I have installed recent beamer (3.36 from 2015/01.05).

Comment: @Zarko: Well, I can't, but I haven't updated on my notebook for some days

Comment: @Zarko: I just updated and still can't compile the example by the O.P.

Comment: I test your code modified as follows:  `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\title{title}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\author{\sout{G.~Aad et.~ al.}}
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}` and it works as I say, however if I move `\author{....}` before `begin{document}`, than I receive error even with your `\newcommand` solution.

Comment: @Zarko: Yes, the error is the same what the O.P. says -- I said nothing different, however, I used the macro inside `\author` after `\begin{document}` -- it works then

Comment: @ChristienHupfer, o.k., solution than is not use to `newcommand` macro but move declaration for `\author{\sout{....}}` after `\begin{document}` ... :-). Anyway, I do understand why one will strike out author name ... but this is another story :-)

Comment: @Zarko: Striking out to emphasize that the relevant author (supervisor?) hasn't contributed at all to the presentation/article but request his/her name to be included? ;-)

Comment: @Zarko: I found the culprit: `sout` is fragile and must be robustified.

Comment: this is nice to hear (see :-)). Meantime I test package `soul` and its `st` had the same problem. And thank you to pointed me to possibilities for robusting of macros. I was not aware before for this. Good to know this!

Comment: @Zarko: Actually I answered a different question this day where exactly `\robustify` was needed and it come to my mind that this could be the 'solution' to this answer as well. It's rather coincidence. All (?) those `\textit` etc. and font related commands seem to be fragile